# How to see WAN password in GPON Home Gateway?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, passwords, internet-connection

i have new Alcatel-Lucent router, which is installed by man from my ISP. When i see WAN settings, there is username and password stored there.

I want to know that password.

Can i reveal that password? I already trying change the HTML script using inspect element

```
<input type="password" name="pppoe_password" size="20" maxlength="62">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="pppoe_password" size="20" maxlength="62">
```

But still not working, and the password turning into a strange symbols. How to reveal the 'real' password?

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4BuF.png)

Comment: The router is restricting you from retrieving the password. It very likely has the password stored somewhere in it's storage, but does not want to allow you to retrieve it for security reasons. Do you have information on what model the router is? Your best bet would be to reach out to your ISP and request that they change/reset your password for you.

Comment: My router is Alcatel Lucent G-240w-A . I've been googling and google said i need access to telnet to see the password. But i can't find their default password :(

Comment: Based on this link: https://www.router-reset.com/reset-manuals/Nokia/G-240W-F - They appear to be using randomly generated credentials, that are likely only known by the network operator.

Comment: Although, another similar model router appears to have bad default credentials: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/65pldm/trying_to_log_in_to_alcatellucent_f240wa_router/ - Perhaps trying admin:admin may work for the telnet login.